# Evaluate definite integral $\int_0^{e^{\pi}} |\cos\ (\ln x)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>
> $$ \int_0^{e^{\pi}} |\cos\ (\ln x)|dx$$

*My ideas:* I substituted $u = \ln x$ and tried to evaluate

$$\int_{-\infty}^\pi |\cos u|\ e^u du$$

Integration by parts didn't yield any results however. Does anybody have another idea?

Comment: It should be $-\infty$

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio, My bad, it was a typo, you are right.

Comment: From where did you get this integral?

Comment: @Zacky, a course preparation at my university.

Comment: Divide into intervals, where $\cos x > 0$ and where $\cos x < 0$.  Evaluate these integrals.  You end up with a geometric series to sum.

Comment: @GEdgar, that works really smoothly, thanks.

Comment: @Atticus I see, do you also have the result by any chance? 
I tried something and I'm getting $\frac{e^\pi}{\pi}+\frac{e^\pi}{2}+\frac{2e^{\pi}}{\pi}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{(4n^2+1)}$. I'll try again maybe later though.

Comment: @Zacky, I just got a solution thanks to GEdgar's hint. I got $\frac 12e^\pi
+
e^{\pi/2}
\cdot
\frac 1{1-e^{-\pi}}$. I'm gonna type it as an answer.

Comment: I've obtained above using the fourier series of $|\cos x|$. In order to finish that series one can use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{2a}\operatorname{csch}\left(a\pi\right)-\frac{1}{2a^2}$, but I'd say this approach isn't that nice. We can deduce the value of the series from above combining both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{e^{\pi}}|\cos (\ln x)| dx= -\int_{-\infty} ^{\pi} e^t~ |\cos t| dt$$
$$\implies I=-\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{t} |\cos t|~ dt-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{t} \cos t ~dt+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} e^{t} \cos t~ dt$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} |\cos t|~ dt-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{t} \cos t ~dt+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} e^{t} \cos t~ dt$$
Let $$J=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} |\cos t| ~dt = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n\pi} e^{-t} |\cos t| dt =[(1+e^{-\pi}+e^{-2\pi}+e^{-3\pi}+....+e^{-n\pi}] K$$ $$\implies J=\frac{K}{1-e^{-\pi}}$$ 
Because the period of $|\cos t|$ is $\pi$, so in above we have broken in sections $[0,\pi], [\pi, 2\pi],[2\pi, 3\pi],.....[(n-1)\pi,  \pi]$. Here $K=\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-t} |\cos t| dt$
$$\implies I=J-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{t} \cos t ~dt+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} e^{t} \cos t~ dt$$
by integration by part we have,
$$\int e^{t} \cos t dt =\frac{1}{2} e^{t} [\cos t+ \sin t]~~~~(*)$$
$$I=J-\frac{1}{2}[e^{\pi}+2e^{\pi/2}-1]$$
Using (*)
$$K=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-\pi}+2 e^{-\pi/2})$$
So we finally get 
$$I=\frac{e^{\pi}-1+2e^{\pi/2}}{2(e^{\pi}-1)}+\frac{e^{\pi}+2e^{\pi/2}-1}{2}=\frac{e^{\pi}(e^{\pi}-1+2e^{\pi/2})}{2(e^{\pi}-1)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on GEdgar's hint.

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{e^{\pi}} |\cos (\ln x) |\; dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\pi} |\cos u |\; e^u \; du\\
&= \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} |\cos u |\; e^u \; du +\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \int_{-k\pi -\pi/2}^{-k\pi +\pi/2} |\cos u |\; e^u \; du \\
&= \left| \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \cos u \; e^u \; du \right| +\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty} \left|\int_{-k\pi -\pi/2}^{-k\pi +\pi/2} \cos u \; e^u \; du\ \right| \\
&= \left|\ \left[ \frac12(\sin u+\cos u) \; e^u \right]
_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\
\right|
+
\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}
\left|\
\left[
\frac12(\sin u+\cos u) \; e^u
\right]
_{-k\pi -\pi/2}^{-k\pi +\pi/2}\
\right|
\\
&=
\frac 12e^\pi
+
2
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\frac 12 e^{-k\pi +\pi/2}
\\
&=
\frac 12e^\pi
+
e^{\pi/2}
\cdot
\frac 1{1-e^{-\pi}}\ .
\end{aligned}$$